# Message doesn't show once

Tags: vba, excel

I don't understand why I get the error message repeated many times when data is inserted wrong more then 2 times i.e. column A. So if 3 mistakes are in column A, then the message pops up 3 times. I set Mwarning as boolean but I guess it is not set properly.

Can anyone guide me in solving this issue?

```
    Dim aRec As Worksheet, bRec As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim match
    Dim Mwarning As Boolean
    Dim c as long


    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set aRec = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set bRec = wb.Worksheets(2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For c = 2 To aRec.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        match = Application.match(aRec.Cells(c, 1).Value, bRec.Columns(2), 0)

        If IsError(match) And Not IsEmpty(aRec.Cells(c, 1)) Then
             aRec.Cells(c, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
             MsgBox "Mistakes are in column A", vbInformation, "IMPORTANT:"
             Mwarning = True
        Else
            aRec.Cells(c, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        End If

    Next c

    If Mwarning = True Then MsgBox "No errors found!", vbInformation, "IMPORTANT:" ' if an error is set in column A, then do nothing, otherwise get the next message


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: This looks like Excel VBA, not Access VBA. Is that correct? If yes, can you change tags?

Comment: Your msgbox is launched inside a for loop. It's a loop. It will execute the code inside of it many many times. I have properly indented your code so you can see that the `If` is inside of a loop. If you want the program to exit the for loop when an error is encountered then stick `Exit For` after `MWarning=true`. Alternatively, remove the `MsgBox` line inside the `If` statement in the loop so only the final `MsgBox` outside the loop fires. Once.

Comment: You can also say  If Mwarning Then and don't have If Else all on one line.

Comment: BTW, if you found error, you set Mwarning to true, and then if Mwarning is true you display a message saying there were no error, isn't it the opposite?

Comment: @jNevil the reason why I would like to stick with the 1st MsgBox inside the if statement is because I have this code stated under a button that checks not only column A, but other columns as well. So when the error gets into one specific column, I want that column to be identified i.e. column A. So the overall idea is that I have that code multiple times under one button, but with different columns to be verified and matched. Hope is clear

Comment: It isn't at all clear. You are in a loop so that msgbox will fire every time that a row encounters an `IsError(match) and Not IsEmpty(aRec.Cells(c,1))` condition. It's very confusing. You are setting `mWarnings = true` when that condition is encountered. Meaning you found an error. Then when the loop is complete you say `If Mwarning = true then msgbox "No Errors Found"` What is that about? You found an error if Mwarning is true. Perhaps `If Mwarning Then msgbox ("Errors found in column A") Else msgbox("No errors Found!")` would be more appropriate. Again removing the msgbox in the loop.

Comment: You have to watch your control variable.  1- First you should initialize it to False right away. After it is created.  2 - I am pretty sure you want the "no error" msgbox to be a false condition, since your loop msgbox fires on true.  Make that change.  3 - Place AND Mwarning = False at the end of your IF statement.  The column A will only fire once if triggered, and your No Errors found will only trigger if no errors were found.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that approach, and it does the job, but as I said I have that code repeated more times under the button. So the same code is written i.e. column B. If I set in the second code Mwarning2 = True (for column B), then when I will get an error I have to write again - If Mwarning2 Then msgbox ("Errors found in column B") Else msgbox("No errors Found!") - and so on.. Then when I will press the button, if i.e. there is no error, I will get 2 times the MsgBox "No errors found".

Comment: The answer is below.  I translated my comment into your code.  You msgbox reports on A and your columns are hard coded at 1, so I do don't understand what you are saying about column B, if you want to port this for any column we need to rework the code further.

Comment: The sub gets called each time you press the button, you will get a msg (or 2) every time you press the button.  If you only want the msgbox to appear once no matter how many times the button is pressed, you have to check if the button has been pressed previously in the button click code. This likely involves setting a global variable in your worksheet open, toggle it if it has not been pressed before and call your sub, if it has been pressed do nothing and exit the button press sub. That is not the question you asked however.

Comment: yes, I understood the problem now and I will try to find another approach now. The best one that fits my code is the one suggested by JNevile as it still tracks the mistakes of the specific cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :** 
Replace you msgbox in the loop by a log like this and add only one msgbox at the end of the sub :

```
Sub testMsg()

   Dim aRec As Worksheet, bRec As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim match
    Dim c As Long


    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set aRec = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set bRec = wb.Worksheets(2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim log As String
    log = ""

    For c = 2 To aRec.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        match = Application.match(aRec.Cells(c, 1).Value, bRec.Columns(2), 0)

        If IsError(match) And Not IsEmpty(aRec.Cells(c, 1)) Then
             aRec.Cells(c, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
             log = "Mistakes are in column A"
        Else
            aRec.Cells(c, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        End If

    Next c

    If log = "" Then
    MsgBox "No errors found!", vbInformation, "IMPORTANT:" '
    Else
    MsgBox log, vbInformation, "IMPORTANT:"


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You add a msgbox function in a loop `MsgBox "Mistakes are in column A", vbInformation, "IMPORTANT:"`
So I think that msgbox will be repeated every time if the IF condition is encountered.

Comment: I went this route as well, but the addition is capturing the rows where the errors are located, seems he hinted at that in a comment to @alex2002

Answer (score 1):

You add a msgbox function in a loop `MsgBox "Mistakes are in column A", vbInformation, "IMPORTANT:"`
So I think that msgbox will be repeated every time if the IF condition is encountered.
Delete this.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: improved answer that leaves the cell coloring alone without adding another IF. Msg will only fire once, the Row locations will be reported in a single msgbox as the error string is built inside of your loop, be careful if there are many errors.

```
Dim aRec As Worksheet, bRec As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Dim match
Dim Mwarning As Boolean
Dim c As Long
Dim rpt As String


Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set aRec = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set bRec = wb.Worksheets(2)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Mwarning = False 'Always, Always, Always set an intitial condition
rpt = "WARINING: Column A Errors are Found" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

For c = 2 To aRec.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    match = Application.match(aRec.Cells(c, 1).Value, bRec.Columns(2), 0)

'Added the piece that if there is an error, check if the box has already fired = true,
'if it has NOT fired, then fire it once and not again
    If IsError(match) And Not IsEmpty(aRec.Cells(c, 1)) Then
         aRec.Cells(c, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         Mwarning = True
         rpt = rpt & "Error Found at Row: " & c & vbNewLine
    Else
        aRec.Cells(c, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If

Next c

'You only want this to pop if no errors are found in the FOR LOOP
If Mwarning = False Then
    'if no error was found report this message
    MsgBox "No errors found!", vbInformation, "IMPORTANT:"
Else 'error was found in column A so Mwarning is true
    MsgBox rpt, vbInformation, "IMPORTANT:"

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, the code does show only one time, but the problem is that it doesn't  point anymore to the red cells where the mistakes are. So for example if I have mistakes in cell A5 and A6, the cell that will turn red will only be the cell A2.

Comment: I forgot about your color coding, let me adjust.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `Mwarning` as Booleanand you set it to `True` when a mistake is found, but you do not check for its value in the loop. So, the `if` in the loop should also check for `Mwarning` value.